# parameter order independent function call

Tags: c#

is there a way to implement below scenario of function as a single call, so that for caller it looks like singe call (If not i can declare them as 2 overloaded calls, but checking if language has some feature)

Add(int, dateTime)

Add(datetime, int)

so that caller can call Add(2, DateTime.Now) Or Add(DateTime.Now, 2).
My scenario is that arguments to pass will come in an array, and i want caller can just call Add(args[0], args[1])

I can't use parameter name here as any parameter can be of any type. basically i want to have equivalent of 
DateTime + int 
int + dateTime

Comment: you could use `params object[]` but that is pretty hairy if the objects are not the same type. How would you deal with that in the method?

Comment: Single call?  No, unless you make both parameters an object, which isn't useful.  Just create the two functions, put your logic in one function, and have the other function call it with the reversed parameters.

Comment: Two overload with different parameter orders.

Comment: Two overloads with different parameter orders (but otherwise identical parameters) is bad practice, in my opinion. Users of your API will likely be somewhat confused as to which one to use, or what the differences between them are.

Comment: @RufusL s/somewhat confused/murderously enraged/ but otherwise yeah

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just picking the order of arguments that makes sense to you, and sticking with that. Having multiple overloads of the exact same argument list in different orders is non-conventional and potentially confusing to consumers of your API.

One thing that can be done when calling methods is using Named Arguments. If your consumers use named arguments, they can put them in whatever order they want.

For example:

```
public static DateTime Add(int daysToAdd, DateTime date)
{
    return date.AddDays(daysToAdd);
}

private static void Main()
{
    // Call the method passing the int first, then the DateTime
    var newDate1 = Add(daysToAdd: 5, date: DateTime.Now);

    // Call the method passing the DateTime first, then the int 
    var newDate2 = Add(date: DateTime.Now, daysToAdd: 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no specific language feature for that.

In such cases you could use `params object[]` to give 0 or more parameters to the method, but I highly doubt that will ever give a decent working piece of code with is not error-prone. It means you have to cast every parameter to the desired type when you want to use them as such.

If you the types are hard-coded on the calling side, it is better to keep 1 single method.

Answer (score 0):

1. define one of them, for exemple:

   ```
   Add(int offSet, DateTime dataTime)
   ```

   then use it like this

   ```
   Add(offSet:2,dataTime:DateTime.Now) 
   Add(dataTime:DateTime.Now,offSet:2)
   ```
2. you can as well create a new method:

   ```
   Add(DateTime dateTime, int offSet){
       Add(offSet,dateTime );
   }
   ```